# I getting "invalid session id"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My issue is for the first time I am implementing data driven framework and I am able to run the program and it is getting executed and I am able to take the screen shot as well.But the issue is I am getting below mentioned error in my console which will of course reflects in my report. Please suggest what should I do and in case of any other information, please ask the same.

Console Error : -

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException:  invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

I am using Test NG also to get the results.

Regards,
Sunil

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error trace log

Comment: dude please share script that you are try to run

Comment: Please find the below script-:public void initialization(){
      // To set the path of the Chrome driver.
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
       
      // To launch facebook
      driver.get("https://www.mahindrafirstchoice.com/sell");

Comment: Then I tried giving EXPLICIT WAIT so that it will open my website and will select the city -:: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
      
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal show']/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")));
      
      //TO SELECT CITY
      
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal show']/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
      
      }

Comment: Hi Debanjan, please find my console error and session ID --:   invalid session id
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'  System info: host: 'DESKTOP-MO0FC5C', ip: '192.168.3.148', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'

Comment: Session ID: 112ddd472d778af7469463947d16f153

Comment: When you add information, please edit the info into your question so that future readers don't have to read all comments to get all the relevant data.

Comment: ok, but is there anyone who can help me with the answer, coz m completely stuck and not able to proceed further. As I am new to this website, I am not aware which informations should i fill.

Answer (score 2):

Check your chrome browser, it might got updated.
The chrome driver which you are using is not supporting the updated chrome browser

Check the version of the chrome browser and update your driver accordingly.

then execute the script.